# What's the correct onomatopoeia to refer to a bursting/splattering sound?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example sentence:

> The gases inside the whale built up until [...], it burst,
>   splattering blood and guts over shops and cars around.

I thought of *puff* but a native English speaker told me that *puff* and splattering are mutually exclusive?

Comment: There is considerable freedom in English to construct your own onomatopoeia for such a specific context - *eg*: "...until *BLOORK!!...shplitter*, it burst,..."

Comment: Well, for splattering I would say "splat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pop" is a great option here. It describes a sound created by a sudden release of pressure.

Your whale is popping open, due to the gasses, the splattering comes as the material falls to the ground after.

"Pop: (verb) make a light explosive sound."

For a louder, more intense burst consider "boom"

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [***kablooey***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/kablooey)

defined by Oxford Dictionaries as:

> *exclamation*
>   Used to convey that something has happened in an abrupt way:
>   *and, kablooey! The whole damn thing exploded!*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a different word for *splattering*, like *showering*, and use *splat* for the onomatopoeia. *Splat* is onomatopoeia for a wet impact. I agree with your friend that *puff* is not excellent for your use.